# numerical integration of an integral with singularity

Tags: numerical-integration, complex, singularity

I want to compute the following integral numerically in Mathematica,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dw' \;\frac{\Gamma(\delta-4iw') 4^{4iw'}}{(i(w'-1)+\epsilon)^{1-4iw'}}
$$

where $0<\epsilon, \delta≪1$.You can see that there is a singularity at x=1. I do not want to use contour integration or give $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ different numerical values. To clarify, I give this example.

$$\int_{-∞}^{∞}dx\frac{f(x)}{[i(x−1)+ϵ]}=C.P.V∫_{-∞}^{∞}dx \frac{f(x)}{x−1}+iπf(1),$$
where C.P.V stands for Cauchy Principal value. Mathematica is able to find the first term by using the Cauchy principal value method. So I know how to compute this integral numerically. But as you can see, in the first integral the power of $i(w'−1)+ϵ$ is $1−4iw'$. That is why I do not know how to compute that integral numerically. Could you please help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Try: `NIntegrate` for me works fine.

Comment: I am using NIntegrate too, but when I decrease the values of epsilon and delta, the result will change and does not converge to a number.

Comment: This seems to converge? (no garanties!) `g[\[Epsilon]_, \[Delta]_] := 
 NIntegrate[Gamma[\[Delta] - 4 I w] 4^(4 I w)/
    (I (w - 1) + \[Epsilon])^(1 - 4 I w),
  {w, -Infinity, 1 + I \[Epsilon] // Evaluate, Infinity}, 
  PrincipalValue -> True]` e.g. `Table[g[-1/2, 10^-i], {i, 3, 5}]`

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this, unfortunately the answer was wrong.

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you give a Mathematica expression for your integrand

Comment: This is the Mathematica expression for my integral:

F[ep_ , delta_] :=   NIntegrate[Gamma[delta - 4 I w] 4^(4 I w)/     (I (w - 1) + ep)^(1 - 4 I w),   {w, -Infinity, Infinity}]

Comment: this converges (for me): `Table[NIntegrate[(Gamma[10^(-m) - 4*I*w]*4^(I*4*w))/(I*(w - 1) + 
      10^(-m))^(1 - 4*I*w), 
     {w, -Infinity, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 30], {m, 1, 20}]`